# How to pass button tag to prepareForSegue

Tags: iphone, button, xcode5, segue

In Xcode (iPhone application) I have created a number of buttons programatically like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // By Road Button
    byRoadButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    byRoadButton.tag = 3;
    byRoadButton.frame = CGRectMake(20, 246, 280.f, 40.f);
    UIImage *roadButton = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gettingHereByRoadButton.png"];
    [byRoadButton setBackgroundImage:roadButton forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:byRoadButton];
    [byRoadButton addTarget:self action:@selector(byRoadButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

Then I check which button is pushed in action:@selector, and call performSegueWithIdentifier. The NSLog shows the correct button tag here as a check.

```
- (void) byRoadButtonClicked
{
    NSLog(@"Button Pushed Tag Number: %d", byRoadButton.tag);
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"gettingHereSegue" sender:self];
}
```

But how do I pass the button tag to prepareForSegue? The idea is to pass this tag to prepareForSegue, and based on the tag number, I pass the information associated with that button to the next ViewController?

I have tried:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"gettingHereSegue" sender:byRoadButton.tag];
```

But get an error saying Im trying to pass an int instead of an id.

In my prepareForSegue I have the following:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // ThIS IS WHAT I WANT TO DO - PSEUDO CODE
    //int tagNumber = sender;
    //if (tagNumber == 3)
    //{
          //Set relevant content of Object here
    //}

    //THIS IS WHAT I CURRENTLY HAVE - NO CHECK FOR TAG
    GettingHereContent *gettingHereContent = [[GettingHereContent alloc] init];
    gettingHereContent.content = @"This is my custom content based on this buttons click";

    GettingHereViewController *vc = (GettingHereViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    vc.gettingHere = gettingHereContent;   
}
```

Or can anyone suggest a solution or maybe a better way to do this please?

Comment: Try [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"gettingHereSegue" sender:byRoadButton]; and then in prepareForSegue if (byRoadButton.tagNumber == 3)
   {
          //Set relevant content of Object here
   }

Comment: Yeah that worked perfect thanks. And in prepareForSegue all I had to do then was check if button was equal to sender like this: if (byRoadButton == sender)
    { // Do something here } I did not have to worry about the tag number to check for button clicks. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

```
  // try This replace with your code
 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"gettingHereSegue" sender:byRoadButton];

-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(UIButton *)sender
{
  NSLog(@"%ld",(long)sender.tag);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"gettingHereSegue" sender:byRoadButton];
```

and then in prepareForSegue

```
if (sender.tagNumber == 3) { //Set relevant content of Object here }
```